# How to repeat functionality in program

Tags: python

I am working on a simple Python program where the user enters text and it says something back or executes a command.

Everytime I enter a command, I have to close the program. Python doesn't seem to have a `goto` command, and I cannot enter more than one "elif" without an error.

Here is the part of the code that gives me an error if I add additional `elif` statements:

```
cmd = input(":")
if cmd==("hello"):
    print("hello   " + user)
    cmd = input(":")
elif cmd=="spooky":
    print("scary skellitons")
```

Comment: you can simply use while(1==1), after you remove the second input.

Comment: even better: `while True`

Comment: If you use `while(True)` you'll need to make sure you have a command that does a `break` or something to exit the loop, otherwise the program will never end.

Comment: just a quick note : if someone taught you to use goto then you need to go back and be taught by someone who has a clue. goto is a really bad idea in most cases, it is far better to use loop constructs like while, for etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way to deal with different responses based on user input:

```
cmd = ''
output = {'hello': 'hello there', 'spooky': 'scary skellitons'}
while cmd != 'exit':
    cmd = input('> ')
    response = output.get(cmd)
    if response is not None:
        print(response)
```

You can add more to the `output` dictionary, or make the output dictionary a mapping from strings to functions.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is only coded to execute once from what you've posted. If you want it to accept and parse the user input multiple times, you'll have to explicitly code that functionality it.

What you want is a `while` loop. Take a look at [this page](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_while_loop.htm) for a tutorial and [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/compound_stmts.html#while) for the docs. With `while,` your program would have the general structure of:

```
while True:
    # accept user input
    # parse user input
    # respond to user input
```

`while` statements are part of the larger [flow control](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/controlflow.html).